# Variable substitution in pattern matching?

Tags: c++, variables, pattern-matching, expert-system

I'm developing an inference engine, this means that basically I have a certain number of "facts" which are basically the representation of the world in a certain moment. Together with the facts (that usually are only two, the starting state and the goal state) I have many rules (could literally be hundreds for certain problems). The aim of the inference engine is, given a start state and a set of rules, find the shortest path to the one of the acceptable goal states. This can be done with several algorithms like DFS, BFS or A*. The basic structure for the program is:

```
fact factname
  attribute1 = "value";
  attribute2 = [ 1, 2, 3];
  attribute3 = 4;
  attribute4 = 7;
  ...
endFact

rule ruleOne
  equalsto(attribute, "value") or
  greaterthan(attribute, 5)
  >
  remove(attribute);
endRule

rule ruleTwo
  isprimeinteger(attribute)
  >
  add(attribute, 1)
endRule
```

In the rule, the LHS (the part before the >) matches *every* attribute in the fact `factname` which is equal to "value". In this case it's only one, but there may be many.
This means I have to resolve variables (often multiple times for the same fact), and the rule's LHS may have multiple conditions put in and/or with proper priority parsing.

The problem is: is there any way to resolve this kind of variables **efficiently**? What I'm doing now is to iterate over every attribute in the fact and basically I'm generating a quite big n-ary tree which is even unbalanced, and this is VERY slow, especially given the conditions above.

I'd love pointers to papers for this kind of pattern matching

Comment: Can you explain your problem a bit more precise? I have a hard time understanding it. How do you get the states that can be reached from a given state? What do you mean with variables? (I can only see 'attribute', which seems to be a very special variable. Are there any others?) I can't detect any pattern matching (or unification) and also fail to see the relevance of the tags 'expert-system' and 'c++'. Finally, DFS doesn't seem to be a great choice if you want a shortest path.

Answer (score 2):

I noticed you didn't use the word **unification** any where in your post.  That's what's the algorithm you're trying to implement is generally called.  Check out the [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unification) article; there's some references at the bottom .. including one from the '70s when space and cycles mattered.

Answer (score 0):

No big surprise here, you're using an O(N) algorithm where a straightforward hashtable would be O(1). The hashtable would store for each attribute value the corresponding attribute.

Comment: No, a hashtable is not useful in this case. Maybe the example doesn't give the idea, but I may have something like this in the LHS: greaterthan(variable_name, 2) and this must give to variable_name *all* the fact's attributes whose value is greater than two (and there may be many).

Comment: Better update the example with that condition, and while you're at it, add "isprimeinteger(attribute)" if that's possible to.

The root problem is that any efficient solution will take advantage of structure to eliminate the O(N) list walk. No structure, no efficiency.

Answer (score 0):

eduffy has it: this is called unification. Prolog is a programming language designed to do exactly what you're trying to do, in the general case, and it uses unification to do its dirty work.

However, anyone who's tried to implement arithmetic using Peano axioms in Prolog can tell you it doesn't always get there the fastest way possible. There are "constraint programming" languages that do roughly the same thing but with an emphasis on providing heuristics to help the solver find optimal solutions as quickly as possible. One of them is [Comet](http://www.comet-online.org/Welcome.html).